# Moving to jdk11, gradle multi-project build problem: modules are not supported in -source8

Tags: gradle, kotlin, java-platform-module-system

I'm moving some libs to openjdk11 using the third approach described [here](https://blog.joda.org/2018/03/jpms-negative-benefits.html).
The whole project is being compiled into 8, while only `module-info.class` to 11.

In the process of doing this, I found out that writing an empty `main` somewhere and running it, is the quickest way to check if there are any missing dependencies, the `module-info.java` has been properly detected and configured (because apparently `gradle build` is not that reliable).

I already did this for [glm](https://github.com/kotlin-graphics/glm), which has two modules, decleared in the same [`build.gradle`](https://github.com/kotlin-graphics/glm/blob/master/build.gradle#L103)

Now I'm testing [`uno`](https://github.com/kotlin-graphics/uno-sdk), but unfortunately I keep getting this error

```
Error:(1, 1) java: modules are not supported in -source 8
  (use -source 9 or higher to enable modules)
```

My question is, why do I keep this error, when `glm` works fine?